# How to enable a major + a minor mode on loading a file?

Tags: eval-expression, auto-mode-alist

Clojure files should open in Clojure-mode. I also have Clojure files that contain color info and are used to generate my styles; they live under a /styles path. For these files, I want them to have both clojure-mode (a major mode) and rainbow-mode (a minor mode). I can implement this on a file-by-file basis be starting such files with a line like this:

`;; -*- eval: (rainbow-mode) -*-`

But I make and use enough of these files, I tried the following:

```lisp
(use-package rainbow-mode
:mode "css\\|style")
```

Which adds that line to the top of `auto-mode-alist`. But that causes the auto-mode to no longer match my clojure files if they dwell under a `style/*` directory; it enables the rainbow minor mode and stops there. Is there a simple solution for getting both of these modes to load on clj files without having to preface every such file with the eval line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `rainbow-mode` in `clojure-mode` only under a certain directory, add a `.dir-locals.el` file to the directory, containing:

```el
((clojure-mode . ((eval . (rainbow-mode 1)))))
```

You can also use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `add-dir-local-variable` to create/edit the file.

Note that `eval` is a pseudo-variable used to evaluate elisp.

Alternatively, with the file in the project root:

```el
(("path/to/subdirectory" . ((clojure-mode . ((eval . (rainbow-mode 1)))))))
```

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Directory Variables` for more details, as well as an equivalent way of specifying this in your init file rather than with a `.dir-locals.el` file.

---

To use `rainbow-mode` in `clojure-mode` whenever the buffer file name contains `/style/` or `/css/`:

```el
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook #'my-clojure-mode-hook)

(defun my-clojure-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `clojure-mode' behaviours."
  (and buffer-file-name
       (string-match "/\\(?:style\\|css\\)/" buffer-file-name)
       (rainbow-mode 1)))
```

Comment: I guess there's no harm in turning on rainbow mode in every Clojure buffer, but I was hoping to have it only in those under "style" or "css" directories like with the automode functionality

Comment: Sorry, I didn't grok the question properly.  You can do that with directory-local variables.  I'll update the question.

Comment: You can also alter my-clojure-mode-hook to check on the buffer's directory and only execute the (rainbow-mode 1) is in a relevant one.

Comment: @mmmmmm Good idea.  I've made that change.

Comment: Solves the problem and also demonstrates a cool use of (and) to make an if/when unnecessary!